# SonataAdmin. Console not recognizing Sonata commands

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How to configure SonataAdminBundle to use Sonata [commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/console.html)?

Cause I got:

> sonata:admin:list
>
> Cannot run program "sonata:admin:list" (in directory "C:\wamp64\www\foo"): CreateProcess error=2

I installed SonataAdminBundle  "version": "3.9.0", on Symfony 2.8 by:

> composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle

Comment: Did you forget to run the command from within the symfony console? `app/console sonata:admin:list` :)

Comment: thanks for response. In my phpstorm console I can run all other commands (doctrine: ,fos: etc) without a problem.